# rails running in staging on production machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, config, staging

I have a machine where all my rails apps are running in a "staging" environment, even the production ones.  It is trying to connect to the staging database.  I have tried setting it set to production in the following places:

```
#/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/passenger.so: 
# the line above was wrong, it is in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ier

RailsBaseURI /ier
RailsEnv production
<Directory /rails/production/ier/current/public>
  Options -MultiViews
</Directory>

#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
Rails.env = 'production'
```

I even tried putting it in:

```
#config/environment.rb adding Rails.env = 'production'
```

I am getting a passenger error of:

```
staging database is not configured (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
```

I even ran ( grep -R "staging" . in ) and got:

```
Binary file ./.git/index matches
./config/deploy.rb:set :stages, %w(staging production)
./config/deploy.rb:#    %w{staging.rb}.each do |config|
./config/deploy.rb:#    %w{production.rb staging.rb}.each do |deploy_env|
./config/database.yml:staging:
grep: ./config/deploy/staging.rb: No such file or directory
grep: ./config/deploy/production.rb: No such file or directory
```

I am running Apache2, Passenger 3.0.7, ruby 1.9.2, and rails 3.0.9

Where else can I look to find out where I set the environment to staging?

thanks for any help

Comment: how are you trying to run your server? rails s -e production?

Comment: its an apache virtual site, so it runs when apache starts.  The config includes the passenger code above.  I will add the rest of the code for the virtual site to make that more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this inside your `<VirtualHost>` configuration (probably in `/etc/apache2/site-enabled/000-default`).

```
RailsEnv production
RackEnv production
```

I hear some versions of Passenger required `RackEnv` instead of `RailsEnv` so you might want to try that especially.

You can also try putting it in an `.htaccess` file in your public directory if you have `AllowOverride` set to `Options` or `All`.